# Infinitive is your friend

Tags: riddle

My name is happiness
From two people uniting
When separated I crumble

My surname is law
If you feel wronged
I am your weapon

Readers hate me
Writers avoid me
Who am I?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are:

> Mary Sue

My name is happiness
From two people uniting
When separated I crumble

> A happy union of two people occurs when they **marry**, though distinctly unhappy if it starts to fall apart

My surname is law
If you feel wronged
I am your weapon

> You can **sue** people if they've wronged you, it's a legal process

Readers hate me
Writers avoid me
Who am I?

> A **Mary Sue** is an overly-perfect character in fiction, commonly thought to be the author trying to force an idealised version of themselves into their work. It can be tedious to read.

Addendum: for the title:

> The answer to part 1 is more accurately **marriage** (and part 2 could be **suing**, or similar). You need the infinitive form of the verbs to get the answer (To marry and to sue)

Comment: Aaah, perfect :)